# Median of CAGR in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, median, aggregates

New to Tableau ... I have a calculated field that calculates the CAGR for the last year in Tableau. I want to create another column that calculates the median of the CAGRs but get the error that the CAGR is already an aggregate and cannot be further aggregated.

This is what I have so far for the CAGR:

```
IF INDEX() = 5 // if there is at least 5 years of data
then ZN(POWER(ZN(SUM([Total Conferrals]))/LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Total Conferrals])), FIRST()),ZN(1/(INDEX()-1))) - 1)
ELSE 0
END
```

Is there a way to get Median(CAGR)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For already Aggregated measures Tableau does not allow further aggregation .

You should use `WINDOW-CALC` for these types of scenarios .

In your particular case, you may want to use `WINDOW_AVERAGE('AGGREGATE FUNCTION')`

Let me know if this works for you .

Comment: I think this solves the issue, but I'm not confident I'm getting the results I'm expecting. I ultimately might have to do some of these calculations before loading the data in Tableau, as I may need to do further analysis on the values, and it doesn't seem like it's going to get any simpler in Tableau.

Comment: @harmlessdragon There are more things to do after applying window calculations. You will have to specify the calculation as `TABLE DOWN` or `PANE DOWN` or something else depending upon how you have designed your sheet . Sharing your sheet might help .